# Recognize key combination during start of the app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, keyboard, nsevent

I have an option in my XCode app and i like to switch it like the i Apps: Hold ALT key during the starting of the app... My question is, how can i recognize the key or a key combination in:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification { ... }
```

or in the app delegate?

Any suggestion would be great.

The NSEvent won't be called without a first responder (if i'm right).

Andy

Comment: Where do you get keyboard on app start on mobile phone ? on launch it's all you can do is create root controller and then playing with keyboard in this controller. Until that you only have launch screen.

Comment: Sorry, i mean a normal XCode Objective-C application without Cocoa touch. It run's on the Mac not on an iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

Of course i mean the option key. This does the job:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    if (CGEventSourceKeyState(kCGEventSourceStateCombinedSessionState,0x3A)) {
        NSLog(@"Option key...");
    }
}
```

If someone else need it.

Comment: There's also [NSEvent modifierFlags], 
eg: 
    if ([NSEvent modifierFlags] & NSAlternateKeyMask)…